# How to detect when RabbitMQ receiver connection is lost?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I use a RabbitMQ with listener. 
**How can I detect that the connection and listener are working** when there are no data comming from RabbitMQ (empty queue)?

Comment: You can either peek for a message in the queue, or get queue statistics with its count of messages

Comment: hhmm, misread your question! The connection is re-established if broken, unless configured otherwise. So the normal behavior is that it is always connected or will be as soon the hardware let it. But it less important since you declare you queues durable?

Comment: Hi @FrankNielsen, that sounds good. And can I detect when e.G. the RabbitMQ Server is down and so the connection is lost?

Comment: It has some monitoring for when it is blocking, but if any c# libraries supports that i dont know.